# Websocketserver with Flask and gevent in Python

Tags: python, flask, websocket, python-3.5, gevent

I have a WebSocketServer with Flask and gevent. I have my own WebsocketApplication inheriting from WebSocketApplication in which I overrite `on_open(), on_close(), on_message()` and it's working fine. I also have a Method `broadcast_message()` to send a message to all clients, which is working fine as well. 
 Now I need to call `broadcast_message()` from outside my WebSocketApplication (e.g. when a special site is visited), but I didn't find any way to do this. 
 I am using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ws = environ["wsgi.websocket"] to pull up the websocket interface anywhere in your application.